# JSON Tree PHP using a recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

The problem is that each child element is bound to each parent element, which is why everything is duplicated

```
<?php
$json = '[
    {"id":3633,"name":"Mobile phones and accessories","left":1,"right":18,"level":1,"elements":0},
    {"id":3638,"name":"Mobile phones","left":2,"right":3,"level":2,"elements":174},
    
    {"id":21396,"name":"Tablets","left":19,"right":24,"level":1,"elements":0},
    {"id":21450,"name":"Some Tablets","left":20,"right":21,"level":2,"elements":8}
    ]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

function buildTree($data, $level = 1) {
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['level'] == $level) {
            $node = array(
                'item' => $item,
                'children' => buildTree($data, $level + 1),
            );

            $tree[] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

$tree = buildTree($data);

print_r($tree);

?>
```

It turns out that this is the output of the elements

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3633
                    [name] => Mobile phones and accessories
                    [left] => 1
                    [right] => 18
                    [level] => 1
                    [elements] => 0
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3638
                                    [name] => Mobile phones
                                    [left] => 2
                                    [right] => 3
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [elements] => 174
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 21450
                                    [name] => Some Tablets
                                    [left] => 20
                                    [right] => 21
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [elements] => 8
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21396
                    [name] => Tablets
                    [left] => 19
                    [right] => 24
                    [level] => 1
                    [elements] => 0
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3638
                                    [name] => Mobile phones
                                    [left] => 2
                                    [right] => 3
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [elements] => 174
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 21450
                                    [name] => Some Tablets
                                    [left] => 20
                                    [right] => 21
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [elements] => 8
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now I have every element with level = 2 tied to every element with level = 1
But there should be no duplication

What can be changed so that all elements are unique and belong to only one parent

Comment: And what you want to accomplish? What should your desired tree look like?

Comment: @digitalniweb
that is, there is an element with level = 1 (he is the parent), the cycle goes further if the element with level = 2, then he is the child of the previous element and only his

If the next element with level = 1 occurs, then it will already have other children

Comment: You always iterate over all data. You could mark the used ones to not use them again.

Comment: do you want it by parsed by order, all level 1 are siblings, and otherwise each item is a child of the previous?

Comment: @ITgoldman
All level 1 are parents, and all the others are children and children's children (then there is still level = 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- it doesn't handle the case when `$level` is greater than `$item['level']`
- the recursive call uses the same array as first parameter, but doing that doesn't preserve the "pointer" position, and the entire array is scanned at each call from the beginning.

For the first point, a simple `if` suffices to solve the problem.
For the second point I suggest to use an iterator in place of an array to keep the pointer positions trough the different calls.

```
$data = new ArrayIterator(json_decode($json, true));

function buildTree(iterator $data, int $level = 1): array {
    
    $tree = [];
  
    while ($data->valid()) {
        $item = $data->current();
        
        if ($item['level'] < $level)
            return $tree;
  
        if ($item['level'] === $level) {
            $data->next();
            
            $tree[] = [
                'item' => $item,
                'children' => buildTree($data, $level + 1)
            ];
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/AmhMX#v8.2.7)

This code is written for PHP 8.x, feel free to remove the types in the function signature to make it work with older versions.

Comment: thank you very much, it turned out exactly as I wanted 
Now i just need to understand how it works

Comment: @AlexBoyarchuk: the main thing to retain: when you pass an array to a function, it uses a copy of this array in the function body, so no chance for a cursor/pointer position to be preserved when you call the function. Other thing, each time a `foreach` loop is called, the position of the array pointer is reseted too. But when pass an iterator (or any object) to a function, the function doesn't make a copy and works with the object itself. That's why the pointer position is preserved between calls.

Comment: that is, roughly speaking, if you use just an array in a loop without wrapping it in an iterator, then at each iteration the pointer is reset and we can't set it in any way?

Comment: @AlexBoyarchuk: Not at each iteration, at each start of a foreach loop. Also each time you call the function with an array, since it's a copy of the array, it is set to the first position by default. An iterator instance is different, since it contains the last position in itself (it's a property). And when you pass an instance of an object to a function you pass a reference to the instance, not a copy. That's why the last position is preserved.

Comment: this is interesting, I have not encountered this, you are a very good specialist, thank you very much. Can you tell me if you have a YouTube channel or how to keep in touch with you, I would be very grateful

Comment: @AlexBoyarchuk: Sorry, the only YouTube channel I could suggest is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRd2C09s0aQ

Answer (score 0):

If you want it by parsed by order, all level 1 are siblings, and otherwise each item is a child of the previous then here's a javascript pseudo-code.

```js
var arr = [
    {"id":3633,"name":"Mobile phones and accessories","left":1,"right":18,"level":1,"elements":0},
    {"id":3638,"name":"Mobile phones","left":2,"right":3,"level":2,"elements":174},
    {"id":3639,"name":"Mobile phones 2","left":2,"right":3,"level":3,"elements":174},
    
    {"id":21396,"name":"Tablets","left":19,"right":24,"level":1,"elements":0},
    {"id":21450,"name":"Some Tablets","left":20,"right":21,"level":2,"elements":8}
];

var result = [];

var previous = null;
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.level == 1) {
    result.push({item})
    previous = item;
  } else {
    previous.children = previous.children || []
    previous.children.push({item})
    previous = item;
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: yes, your option really works, now I will carefully read everything